# Implementing a sortable list

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI. I have the following HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <div class="left">
    <%= link_to 'NAME', '#' %>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <%= link_to 'SURNAME', '#' %>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <%= link_to 'AGE', '#' %>
  </div>
  </li>

  <li>
  <div class="left">
    Test name1 value
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Test surname1 value
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Test age1 value
  </div>
  </li>

  <li>
  <div class="left">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    ...
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to make that sortable using JavaScript (if possible using jQuery and jQuery UI, not external plugin). That is, by clicking on the `NAME`, `SURNAME` or `AGE` I would like to list items by the "pseudo-column"\"link" clicked.

For instance:

When I click on `NAME` I would like to have:

```
 NAME*     SURNAME     AGE
---------------------------
 Name1     Surname1    20
 Name2     Surname2    25
 Name3     Surname3    30
 Name4     Surname4    24
 ...       ...         ...
```

When I click on `AGE` I would like to have:

```
 NAME      SURNAME     AGE*
---------------------------
 Name1     Surname1    20
 Name4     Surname4    24
 Name2     Surname2    25
 Name3     Surname3    30
 ...       ...         ...
```

**How can I do\code that? What do you advice about** (maybe I have to use a HTML `<table>...` instead of `<ul><li>...`)**?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you have a look at [Railscast 240: Search, Sort, Paginate with Ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax).  Just skip the ajax part if it's unnecessary.

You'll be able to use `<ul>` tags if you prefer them to the `<table>` markup because essentially you are just setting an order param when you click the link.

Comment: Upvote, but I would suggest using [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) rather than will_paginate like shown in this RailsCast.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a table you could use one of the many table / sorting plugins like: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Also i think a table would surely be better suited for that kind of data. (and more semantically correct)

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish that using jQuery\jQuery UI and *not* external plugin?

Comment: They don't have that functionality included but you could write such a plugin yourself if you don't want to use one that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the same thing as Andy: use a js module to do it client side (assuming that the whole set of data is sent to the client at once). I'd recommend [data tables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish that using jQuery\jQuery UI and *not* external plugin?

Comment: You can write your own code of course. Eg. you bind the click event on each sort link to do the following: get the content of the list items, sort in memory, clear the content of the list and then append the sorted list elements. It shouldn't be long to code.

Answer (score 0):

I once tried to make sorting functionality without a plugin. But when i want to make additional functionality like filter, pagination, etc, I became overwhelmed. So i'd recommend [metasearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) for sorting and filtering and combine it with [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for pagination. For ajax, use Chaker Nakhli suggestion. it's worth trying.